# pdf module for play framework 2.3.x

Tags: java, pdf, playframework, pdf-generation, playframework-2.3

I have a application which should generate simple tables as report in pdf. But I cannot find any easy solution. I hoped that I can find some pdf module, but it seems that it does not exist. I found only PDF module for Play Framework 1.x and play20-pdf which is not longer supported. I know that I can use a pdf library listed for example here [What is the best PDF open source library for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6118652/1253130), but I wanted to avoid adding some powerful tool when everything what I need is save simple view with tables as pdf.

Comment: You can use Play Dok, to integrate Applidok generate using PDF template: https://github.com/applicius/play-dok

Comment: Answered in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188374/play-framework-2-render-pdf][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188374/play-framework-2-render-pdf

Answer (score -1):

iReport is one of the most popular solutions (http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer). You can create your PDF report in 'iReport Designer' and then connect it directly to the database or you can fill the report from the java code using jasperreports library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```